# How do I change the default .htm file icon?

Tags: firefox, icons

I really enjoy the look of UBUNTU. The **only** thing that I want to change is the default icon used for .html (.htm) files.  I want to use the icon /usr/lib/firefox/browser/icons/mozicon128.png instead.  I do not want to change any other visual element.  Is there a practical way to accomplish this small change?

edit: @Mitch, I've used assogiate in the past and although I was able to change the icon used for .mht files, I could not get it to change the .htm icon.

@Anwar Shah, thanks for the information. I wish that it would work for me. Running 13.10 x86, after I do the copy of the icons, in the folders are a bunch of links to .svg files not actual graphics files. It appear that the second copy actually went into /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/... and replaced the links there with the renamed .png files.  I hope that nothing too weird happens as a result. I have rebooted a couple of times and nothing seems amiss, but no Firefox icons for the .htm files yet either.

Answer (score 1):

I use a program called AssoGiate.

AssoGiate is an editor of the MIME file types database for GNOME.<sup>Ubuntu Apps</sup>

To install [**AssoGiate** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/assogiate/).

Or

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install assogiate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace the default icons for html files. Since mozilla has only 128 size icon, I'm going to replace with that.

1. First make a copy of the default icons

   ```
   mkdir ~/icons
   cp -r /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/* ~/icons -v
   ```
2. Then replace with the mozilla icons for all sizes

   ```
   sudo cp /usr/lib/firefox/browser/icons/mozicon128.png /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/16/gnome-mime-text-html.svg

   sudo cp /usr/lib/firefox/browser/icons/mozicon128.png /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/22/gnome-mime-text-html.svg

   sudo cp /usr/lib/firefox/browser/icons/mozicon128.png /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/24/gnome-mime-text-html.svg

   sudo cp /usr/lib/firefox/browser/icons/mozicon128.png /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/32/gnome-mime-text-html.svg

   sudo cp /usr/lib/firefox/browser/icons/mozicon128.png /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/48/gnome-mime-text-html.svg

   sudo cp /usr/lib/firefox/browser/icons/mozicon128.png /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/64/gnome-mime-text-html.svg

   sudo cp /usr/lib/firefox/browser/icons/mozicon128.png /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/128/gnome-mime-text-html.svg 

   sudo cp /usr/lib/firefox/browser/icons/mozicon128.png /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/256/gnome-mime-text-html.svg
   ```

Then enjoy!
 Here is a screenshot for you after changing the icons. (Thanks to you for this pleasurable hints!)

[image: turn on image to view this]